# Storing constants and appending strings with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, constants

I created a constants.h file to store some global variables in my iOS app.  When I try to access it and append to it in my ViewController, though, I get many errors.

This is what my constant.h file looks like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface constants

#define projectURL @"http://website.com/projects";

@end
```

Then in my view controller, I import the constant file at the top:

```
#include "constants.h"
```

but when I try to log the url with the following:

```
NSLog(@"%@", projectURL);
```

I get the error:

```
Expected ')'
```

Ultimately, what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
NSString *newProjecURLString = [projectURL stringByAppendingFormat: @"/new?auth_token=%@", auth_token];
```

But for this, I get the error:

```
Extraneous ')' before ';'
```

Comment: What the others said.  Plus note that there is no point in placing the #define in an `@interface` -- #define is a preprocessor directive and doesn't know an `@interface` from an `@funnyface`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your `#define` has a `;` at the end so you are ending your line then adding `);`

this is what the compiler is seeing:

`NSLog(@"%@", @"http://website.com/projects";);`

Answer (score 1):

`#define projectURL @"http://website.com/projects";` just replace text before compile.

Before compile your code -- we call precompile

`clang` will replace all `projectURL` in your code with `@"http://website.com/projects";`

So `NSLog(@"%@", projectURL);` will become `NSLog(@"%@", @"http://website.com/projects";);`